# How can I shard mongodb collection by item update time?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I'm developing a web game using mongodb

One of the shards that runs on RAMdisk for the write performance (active)
and other shards run on normal HDD for storage (idle)

The items of each player like:

```
{pid:<uuid-4>, // sharded
 login_at:<Datetime>}
```

It can distribute players according to the pid evenly however what I want is all players who haven't logined in 3 days shard to "idle" .
How can I achieve that?

1. "Date" in this post can't be change due to the shard key is date itself http://blog.mongodb.org/post/85721044164/tiered-storage-models-in-mongodb-optimizing#comment-1387305976
2. http://askasya.com/post/taggedcollectionbalancing only do the collection balancing

Comment: I presume the desired result here is to deliberately create a "hotspot" where the "RAMdisk" shard is taking all the write operations in the current period. This is not really a "programming" question per se, so it really is "off-topic" for the programming related site that StackOverflow is ( I mean is not the name a dead giveaway? ). So really your DBA related question belongs on [dba.stackexchange.con](http://dba.stackexchange.com). The general concept here is "migrating chunks" that fall outside of the expected range to the other "tagged" shards. So basically on the right track.

Comment: Oh yes and I **do** know how to do this. But on principle I will not answer an "off-topic" question here. If you removed and posted to the [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) site instead, then happy to help.

Comment: I don't know how to move this thread to dba.stackexchange.com. Can you help me?

Comment: @BlakesSeven Yes, that's exactly I want.